# Castle Windsor: Register open generics and more complex types with

Tags: generics, castle-windsor, registration

Is it possible with Castle Windsor to register open generics where the generic parameter is an interface.

i.e. I want to be able to resolve `IFruitFactory<IApple>` and get a `FruitFactory<Apple>`?
I would want to do this for any Class that implements IFruit and has an Interface with a name = I(FruitName)

in this case `Apple : IApple` and `IApple : IFruit`

Comment: Do you really need the IApple interface? The real life scenario you have is probably more complex, but it is worth a thought. Make sure you need the additional abstraction level.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ILazyComponentLoader`s](http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2009/11/16/castle-windsor-lazy-loading.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible.

Maybe you can define an

```
IWindsorInstaller<T>
```

somehow, specifically for IFruitFactory<T> ?

But then you'd have to instantiate it explicitly for all the T's that you're going to use. I don't think you can keep it entirely generic and let the container figure it all out.